# Get IE Extension Installation Date from Registry

Tags: internet-explorer, registry

I am Wondering whether there is a way to get Installation date of IE Extension Either from registry or from some Third party High Level API ?

If not from registry directly, Do IE allow extension to access list of all extensions ?

Suggestions & comments will be a great help.

Comment: what is the use case for getting the installation date?

Comment: Need it to get inventory of add-on , & for that i need installation date of add-on.